# Google Chart API - "Request-URI Too Large", but length well below 2048

Tags: google-visualization

I have a strange problem with Google Charts API.

According to the docs, the "GET" limit is 2048 bytes, but I have this one link I created that is well below the limit (1663 bytes) and still chokes the server with a "Request-URI Too Large" error.

Here's the link (check "view source"): [broken chart](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chof=validate&chdl=XXX+cut-off|YYY+cut-off|XXX+Predict+50|XXX+Predict+25|XXX+Predict+75|YYY+Actual|XXX+Actual&chs=750x400&chg=0.334448160535117,12.5,1,5&chls=2,6,3|2,6,3|2,0|2,0|2,0|2,0|2.0&cht=lxy&chm=o,00A8F0,5,-1,8|o,C0D800,6,-1,8&chxs=0,,8.5,0,lt&chxt=x,y&chxl=0%3a|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|150|151|152|153|154|155|156|157|158|159|160|161|162|163|164|165|166|167|168|169|170|171|172|173|174|175|176|177|178|179|180|181|182|183|184|185|186|187|188|189|190|191|192|193|194|195|196|197|198|199|200|201|202|203|204|205|206|207|208|209|210|211|212|213|214|215|216|217|218|219|220|221|222|223|224|225|226|227|228|229|230|231|232|233|234|235|236|237|238|239|240|241|242|243|244|245|246|247|248|249|250|251|252|253|254|255|256|257|258|259|260|261|262|263|264|265|266|267|268|269|270|271|272|273|274|275|276|277|278|279|280|281|282|283|284|285|286|287|288|289|290|291|292|293|294|295|296|297|298|299|300&chd=e%3aAA..,5m5m,AA..,n.n.,AAAOAbApA3BEBSBgBu..,gAlXnDnenxn9n6n9qBqB,AAAOAbApA3BEBSBgBu..,gAckeQeqe-fKfHfJhOhO,AAAOAbApA3BEBSBgBu..,gAuKv2wRwkwwwtwwy0y0,AAAA,gAgA,AAAA,gAgA&chxr=0,0,299,1|1,0,40,5&chco=FF000066,00000066,0000FF66,FF000066,00FF0066,00A8F0,C0D800&chdlp=t)

I'm guessing that it's not really a size problem, but rather some kind of parsing problem in the Google Chart API..?

I have implemented the "form" fallback (to enable 16K requests), but I only want to use this method when the request gets bigger than the allowable 2K.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: The size increases to 1719 bytes when stackoverflow.com escapes the link, but we're still way below 2048.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe lose the 1-300 chxl parameter - it doesn't display well at all. And check your chof=validate. I'm not sure what it does but if I remove both of those things your chart appears perfectly.